# Is it possible to divide a file in blocks and transfer using a library like OkHttp or Volley?

Tags: android

Wanted to know what would be the most efficient way of doing this. The reason I want to divide the file is so that I dont send the same blocks of data again if the network becomes unavailable while the transfer is going on. This is especially usefule for bigger files.

Comment: Use multipart request approach.

Comment: Yes, but that isn't supported by Volley or OkHttp. Wanted to know if it was supported by default. There are extension libraries though which help you use that. Also, I wanted to control the blocks I have sent and the ones I haven't. Is that possible with this approach?

Comment: @dhuma1981 And I also want to control the chunk size of each block.

Comment: where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an **HTTP Multipart Request**, which is provided by the [**Apache HTTP Library**](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html), by [**Retrofit**](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) and by [**Ion**](https://github.com/koush/ion#post-multipartform-data-and-read-json-with-an-upload-progress-bar). `Volley` does not let you perform such a request currently.

Comment: Do these libraries let you control the size of chunks dynamically?

Comment: The part size and network availability are managed internally in these libraries using optimum algorithms.

Comment: The reason I asked this was I want to be able to control the chunk size for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I understood that. What I have seen is that the chunk size is normally controlled internally, so you don't really need to optimize it yourself. If you still need to do this for some other reason, I shall do some research on this and get back to you.

Comment: Would "http.socket.buffer-size" in the DefaultHttpClient class help me achieve that?

Comment: I am not sure that `SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE` is the same as file part size, but kudos for locating that so quickly!